# Does Wear OS supports Android enterprise?

Tags: android, wear-os, enterprise

Does Wear OS supports Android enterprise?
I want to develop device management capabilities for Wear OS smart watches?
How can it be implemented?

Tried to enroll to Android EMM but it didn't work saying Work profile can not be added.